# What is the difference between 打算 (dǎ suàn) and 计划 (jì huà)

Tags: meaning, usage, difference

Are 打算 (dǎ suàn) and 计划 (jì huà) both synonyms for "plan," or are there some additional nuances here?

Comment: ＂汉语动词８００例＂：打算／计划／考虑。 **一、打算** １。他打算再学两年中文。动词＂打算＂的意思是事先预计做什么。＂打算＂的宾语通常是动词或小句。又例如：a。他们打算先在北京参观几天，然后再去上海。b。去不去外国留学，他还没打算好。２。遇到什么事总不能尽为自己打算。＂打算＂在这儿的意思是计算做某事的利害与得失，含有贬义。通常不带宾语：a。她是个精明能干的人，很会打算。 **二、计划** １。他计划用三个月的时间写一篇调查报告。动词＂计划＂的意思是事先拟定好具体的工作内容或行动步骤。又例如：a。他计划着把股票抛出去。b。他们开始计划去国外旅行。 **三、考虑** １。他考虑问题考虑得很全面。动词＂考虑＂的意思是对问题或事情经过仔细思索，衡量是非利弊后，做出决定。又例如：a。不但要考虑青年人的爱好，也要考虑中年老年的爱好。b。这次会议对妇女的要求考虑得不太够。＂打算＂着意在事先预计要做什么；＂计划＂着意在事先拟定出行动步骤。＂打算＂和＂计划＂意思相近，有时可互换。＂考虑＂着意在经过思考后做出决定，跟＂打算、计划＂意思近似，但不能互换。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 打算 means 'intend to'(v) ; 'intention'(n) .

**Edit**:

'打算' can mean 'to plan' (e.g. 为将来打算) or 'intend to' (e.g. 打算将来去英国) in English

A '打算' can be an 'intention' or a 'plan'

> 计划 means 'to plan' (v) ; 'plan' (n).

When you 计划 (plan) something, you are formulating a workable plan with at least some form of mental calculations, and the objective should be a specific one. For example, 政府計劃[*十年內逐步削減赤字, 達到收支平衡*]. Which is a very specific objective

A '计划' is a 'plan'

Answer (score 4):

“计划” is more formal and “打算” is more used in oral language.

"计划" means : You have a goal and you create a plan to achieve that goal.

Example: “我计划去学习” (I want to study and I have a study plan)

"打算" means： You have a goal but you haven't take any actions.

Example：“我打算去学习” (I want to study,  but It’s just a thought)

Comment: 我计划学习 is not a coherent sentence.

Comment: 学习 is not a goal that can be summarized into a plan, If we don't say 我计划恋爱, we can't say 我计划学习 neither

Comment: @TangHo 书面语上的确是不行，但是在口语中没问题。我这个“学习”可以是指，把XX作业做完，或者读完这本书的XX章节， 也可以是制定一个学习计划...等等。谈恋爱是另外一个概念，人什么时候恋爱是不能由自己控制的，但是你可以计划今晚几点写作业。

Comment: 谈恋爱是不能预估的，但是我什么时候去上课，什么时候看书，这些都是可以计划的。

Comment: @Qwert，单纯从语句来说，“我计划学习”的确说不通（即使是口语）。也许你想说的是“我计划*去教室*学习”？

Comment: @LiuYan刘研 改成了“计划去学习”，逻辑更通

Comment: “计划谈恋爱” 严格意义上来讲也行得通，爱是不能被计划的，但是谈恋爱是可以计划的，谈恋爱可以是指交男女朋友/找对象/处对象，这些都是可以计划的。

Comment: “我计划去教室学习”  is still an awkward phrase, the problem is '打算' (intend to) is the more logical choice. using 计划 as a verb is problematic. It requires a specific objective that can be definitely achieved, for example 我计划(三年后到美国学习英語) ; however  we can still replace 计划 with 打算 in this example and write "我打算(三年后到美国学习英語)" which sounds even more natural

Answer (score 3):

计划 vs 打算

Both can be used as verb and noun.

There is overlap in meaning for these two words.

计划 sounds more formal,  implying you have deep thought on it and well planned, maybe you have made a list for things you intend to do, and you might have detailed schedule, budget and etc.

打算 is more colloquial or less formal. It's usually just rough idea about what you are going/wanting to do, and you might not have it well planned.

So, we say 周密的计划，but not 周密的打算. We tend to use 打算 in spoken when you are going to  do something specific(not that complicated or important), like 我打算去逛街，我打算找个朋友聊聊天. We don't usually say 我计划找个朋友聊聊天 in this case, which sounds a bit pretentious I think.