# 《你有什么打算》跟《你有什么计划》一样的吗？

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

最近我对《打算》和《计划》有问题。如果我同事问我《这周末你有什么计划吗？》的话这有《你有什么打算吗？》的意思吗？如果不一样这两个句子有什么不同？

I am a little bit confused on when to use 计划 and when to use 打算. My understanding is that both mean "plan" but they seem to be entirely interchangeable. In what situations would I want to use one over the other?

Comment: Kind of ```plan``` and ```planning```. ```计划``` is probably a bit formal. Also check [this similar Q](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/28516/what-is-the-difference-between-%E6%89%93%E7%AE%97-d%C7%8E-su%C3%A0n-and-%E8%AE%A1%E5%88%92-j%C3%AC-hu%C3%A0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As a noun, both 打算 and 计划 mean "plan" but 打算 also contains the meaning of "intention"

有去美國的计划 (have the plan of going to The United States)

有去美國的打算 (have the plan of going to The United States/ have the intention of going to The United States)

> As a verb, both 打算 and 计划 have the meaning of "plan to", but 打算 also contains the meaning of "intend to"

计划去美國留學 (Plan to to go to The United States to study)

打算去美國留學 (Plan to/intend to go to The United States to study)

Answer (score 1):

they are same, 打算 often used in oral, 计划 is more formal.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to say or mean "a definite plan" has been formulated or decided upon then 计划 is more suitable.

If you want to mean "some kind of decision" has been made, then 打算 is better.

Thus:-

你有什么计划吗？  -- Have you made any plans?

你有什么打算吗？  -- Have you made a decision?